# Get property type of dynamic object in C# (even when value is null)

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dynamic

I have a DynamicObject wrapper that is basically forwarding property values from another private object instance (amongst other things). But is there any way of returning the property-type dynamically as well?

The reason I'm asking is because I'm having trouble with bindings in WPF trying to convert the view-value (**string** in my case with a textbox bound to a double property) to a presenter value of type **object** instead of **double** (which it would if the object was not dynamic and the property had a returntype of double).

If there where something like TryGetMemberType it would be great...

Comment: did you tried Typeof(object.property) ?

Comment: @Ben that is not valid in any type of c#, whether static, polymorphic or dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is not possible with dynamic: a null has no type, and dynamic has no metadata.

In most UI data-binding code, though (including WPF) the primary API is System.ComponentModel - which supports a form of dynamic behavior (and has done since 1.0). Typically, you would use ICustomTypeDescriptor, TypeDescriptionProvider or ITypedList to provide custom PropertyDescriptor instances. These have full metadata, including type information.

I wonder whether this would be a better fit for your needs.